# I'm unable to login in Visual Studio Code to Live Share

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

Whenever I try to Live Share in Visual Studio Code it asks to login with either Microsoft or GitHub, but both of them are unable to open in a new window. I'm unable to login because of that.

[image: screenshot of login issue]

How can I login using GitHub to Live Share in VSCode?

Answer (score 7):

Per [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/vscode#sign-in-using-a-user-code) you can sign in with a "User Code" as a workaround:

1. Ensure you have the latest versions of VS Code and the Live Share Extension installed.
2. Press `Ctrl+Shift+P` or `Cmd+Shift+P` and run the `"Live Share: Sign in with user code"` command.
3. If the browser still does not appear, open the below link in your browser and sign in.
   https://insiders.liveshare.vsengsaas.visualstudio.com/auth/login
4. Once you are done, click `"Having trouble? Click here for user code directions"` to see the user code.
5. Copy the user code.
6. Paste the user code into the input field that appeared when you ran the `"Live Share: Sign in with user code"` command and press enter to complete the sign-in process.

Comment: Thank you for trying. Do you have any additional information to share? Was there a specific step you got stuck on?

Comment: Yeah actually it resolved now thank you. It was browser issue. In default some other browser was selected which I don't use just change the browser to google chrome and now it is working perfectly.

Comment: This seems to be out of date: the _insiders_ link now says: _We have retired this version of Visual Studio Live Share_, and the linked documentation is inconsistent.